# Azure test plans - attaching items to test suites

Tags: testing, azure-devops

In azure test plans, im aware of the ability to attach some sorting test documentation to an individual test.

Does anyone know of a way to attach something at the test suite level? for example id like to attach a spec(or a link to the spec) to a test suite so that it is available as a reference for all test cases in the suite rather than adding the attachment to each test case

Answer (score 0):

By default, a test suite does not support this feature. However, you may open the associated work item and add an attachment:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. when I tried to add the attachment I get 'Active work item does not exist in the current context'  Do you know how to correct that?

Comment: Please open an InPrivate/Incognito window and try the above steps again. If there is the same issue, please check these: 1. If you can add attachments to other work type. 2. If you can add attachments to other test suites.